# Show a given subset is a regular submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I have been trying to show this proposition for hours, Does anybody have an idea how could i do it?
This is the proposition:

[image]

This are the definitions and propositions more important:

[image]

[image]

I wait your help. Thanks

Comment: Duplicate [locally on $S$ one of the coordinates is a $C^∞$ function of the other coordinate. Show that $S$ is a submanifold of $R^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1429061/locally-on-s-one-of-the-coordinates-is-a-c%e2%88%9e-function-of-the-other-coordinat)

Comment: Is this really a duplicate? The OP seems to want slice charts for $S$ which is not the same thing as in the other answer. Admittedly, the proofs are very similar though.